# Bitmap reducing height and width in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to reduce the height and width of the bitmap.I tried using bitmap.CreateSacledBitmap(); It reducing the height and width of the bitmap but the problem the it makes the image blur.I want to do it with out affecting the quality(without blur) of the image.Below is my code:

```
        bitmap = decodeStringToImage(strSignImage);[![Before Scaling][1]][1]
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,100,40,true);
```

[image: After Scaling]

Comment: Are you keeping the aspect ratio?  You're not even looking at it, is the actual image a multiple of 100x40?  If not, its going to have to do weird things to scale it.  How much are you shrinking it, some images aren't just going to shrink well using default techniques.  If this is a signatures and you're shrinking it down by a huge factor, this would be expected as you could be shrinking away the entirety of some skinny lines.  In that case you'd need to write your own shrinker that understands what's important data in the image and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Can try compressing the image with 100% size

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I want to reduce the height and width